# Are there at least $|V|$ Eulerian tours in $G$ if $G$ is even degree and connected? (My proof)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, eulerian-path

I believe there to be  at least $|V|$ Eulerian tours in $G$ if $G$ is even degree and connected, and want to confirm that my reasoning of this is sound. (I am using the definition of Eulerian tour to be a sequence of edges such that each edge is used once, every edge in $G$ is used, and the last edge directs to the starting vertex of this tour). If this is the case of $G$, then there is an Eulerian tour in $G$, and we can enumerate the vertices thereof as $v_1, v_2 \cdots, v_1$, as every vertex lies on the Eulerian tour. We could start an Eulerian tour from any vertex in this enumeration- the vertices describing the Eulerian tour starting from an arbitrary vertex in this enumeration would just continue in the way they are enumerated, but then when the end of this enumeration is reached, we continue this tour from $v_1$, and end where we started from. Therefore there are at least $|V|$ Eulerian tours in $G$, as we can start one from any vertex.

I am wondering if this is correct, as I haven't seen a mention of this fact before, but this might be because it is obvious and not worthy of explicitly mentioning.

Comment: If we distinguish between tours as you state, then the result is trivial imo.

otoh, if we identify Eulerian tours with certain maps from the edges of a graph to the edges of a cycle graph, and then say that two tours are equivalent if there exist such maps that are identical for two tours, which seems more natural to me, then the result is false.

Comment: @user24142 To clarify, do you mean that tours are equivalent if they map to the same cycle graph, rather than if the mapping function with maps the tour to a cycle graph is the same for 2 tours?

Comment: tours of the same length will always map to the same cycle. The size of the cycle is the number of edges in the graph that we are touring. Essentially, I am saying that it is natural to me to not really think of such tours as having a start and finish, just a cyclic list of edges visited. If I have two such lists, and I can cycle one around so that it is identical to the other, then I think of those cyclic lists as the same. The map to the cycle graph formalises this concept.

Comment: Your proof is fine. You can get more mileage from the same idea whenever $G$ has more than two edges, because, once you have an Eulerian tour, you can get another one by tracing it backward: $v_1,v_n,v_{n-1},\dots v_2,v_1$. So you actually get at least $2|V|$ Eulerian tours.